# Why $a^2+b^2=c^2$ is named after Pythagoras? It is known by earlier generations before him such as the Chinese.

Tags: math-history

Why $a^2+b^2=c^2$ is named after Pythagoras? It is known by earlier generations before him such as the Chinese.

It is because he proved it and not other generations? Or Pythagoras put it into applications and it is became well know after that?

Comment: Why is Fermi's Golden Rule named after Enrico Fermi when P.M. Dirac came up with it?

Comment: Why are Euler diagrams called Venn diagrams?

Comment: See [Stigler's law of eponymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigler%27s_law_of_eponymy).

Comment: Whooo??? Sorry mate no idea

Comment: Because it is too lowe

Comment: There is no clear evidence that Pythagoras knew the result.

Comment: Because it is too low for Euler.

Comment: From a traditional point of view, many parts of western civilization (and therefore western mathematics) have roots in the Greeks.

Comment: @AndréNicolas that is very very interesting point. If there is no clear evidence that he knew the result so why it is named after him? Is this and accidental?

Comment: Mathematics I am Very sure that it is started long before the Greek. I don't know why everyone always roots back to the Greek when they started to talk about a maths topics?

Comment: Because most of present day mathematics as we study it was built in the west, and the western intellectual tradition takes ancient Greece as a starting point.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 that is a beautiful answer! Well said!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs to [History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pythagoras](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Pythagoras.html) lived approximately $569-475$ BC.  I am not aware of any evidence of [Chinese mathematics](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/HistTopics/Chinese_overview.html) having the Pythagorean theorem, or anything else for that matter, before then.  It does appear that the [Babylonians](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/HistTopics/Babylonian_Pythagoras.html) knew about it, though we don't know whether they proved it: indeed, as far as we know, the idea of mathematical proof was basically developed by the Greeks, starting with [Thales](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Thales.html).  If not Pythagoras himself, it's likely that someone in his school was the first to prove the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: The chinese version of Pythragoean theorem [勾股定理](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh/%E5%8B%BE%E8%82%A1%E5%AE%9A%E7%90%86) first appeared in [周髀算經](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%91%A8%E9%AB%80%E7%AE%97%E7%B6%93) whose publication date is not known. It is believed to be somewhere between 500BC - 200AD. So you can say that Chinese independently discover it.

Comment: Chinese [proof without words](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Chinese_pythagoras.jpg) in 周髀算經 of 「勾股幂合以成弦幂」, which means 'base, altitude squared combine to give hypotenuse squared'. [Literary Chinese Wikipedia](https://zh-classical.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8B%BE%E8%82%A1%E5%AE%9A%E7%90%86) also gives the accompanying explanatory note.

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not Pythagoras discovered his theorem is a debatable issue. But there are certain evidences that Pythagorean triples are well known before Pythagoras. The [Plimpton $322$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plimpton_322) tablet of Babylonian era, believed to be dated $1800$ BC, contains $4$ columns and $15$ rows of numbers which are regarded as Pythagorean triple. But whether they knew the relation of the number to the triangle is not known.

An Indian text Baudhayana Sulba Sutra, which dated $800$ BC, contains a list of Pythagorean triples and a statement of the Pythagorean theorem. The Apastamba Sulba Sutra (c. $600$ BC) contains a numerical proof of the general Pythagorean theorem, using an area computation.

During the Han Dynasty the Pythagorean triples were appeares in *The Nine Chapters on the Mathematical Art*, together with a mention of right triangles.
In China, the theorem is alternately known as *Shang Gao Theorem*.

More in [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#History)